# How to automatically archive a directory?

Tags: backup

I want to do one way synchronization.

I am having `Folder A` on my computer which is constantly updated with content.
Another `Folder B` is used for backup purpose which is on external HDD.

Now what I expect is that whatever extra which is present in folder A should go to folder B. However something which is present in B and NOT in A ""shall NOT be copied to A"".

In a nutshell, the backup folder may copy everything from the source folder, however nothing should be copied form backup folder to the source.

Comment: That's not synchronization....

Comment: @Braiam what is it called then? I couldn't come up with a word myself like the OP. If you know, please tell.

Comment: @JoSmo copy? Archive? Backup?

Comment: @Braiam thanks, now i feel stupid for asking. :D

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Sounds like a perfect task for rsync

```
sudo rsync -az /path_to/A /path_to/B
```

> -a archive mode (implies recursive, copy symlinks as symlinks, preserve owner, modification times, group, owner, special and device files)
>
> -z compresses the data

If you wish to remove files deleted in A from files in B, use the `--delete` option

For additional information see:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync

You can run rsync from cron

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Add in an hourly task

```
@hourly rsync /path_to/A /path_to/B
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Comment: how can I make a bash script to this so that everytime i connect my portable HDD containing folder B (backup folder), the script runs and copies from A whatever is missing in B.

Comment: alternatively to the above comment... some script which i may manually execute after connecting the drive is also reasonable..

Comment: If there are folders within folders you will need to use the -r option.

Comment: You can make a script by entering it in a file, precede the command with the line: `#!/bin/bash` and add the execute permission to the file with the `chmod` command or using the Ubuntu graphic user interface (File properties--Permission tab). If the file name is 'rs' you can then execute it with `./rs`

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party, but to run the synchronisation script when the hard drive is connected you should use udev. Check out this question from a while ago. http://askubuntu.com/questions/25071/how-to-run-a-script-when-a-distinct-flash-drive-is-mounted

Comment: @JohnSGruber the -a option implies recursive, I'll edit the answer to point this out

Comment: @Tomas, absolutely correct. Thanks for pointing that out and for editing the answer.

Comment: if the files are on the same machine `-z` just slow down the process

Comment: If i delete something in the source directory, will it get deleted in the backup directory? If it does. Is it possible to disable these deletes?

Comment: @JoSmo - http://askubuntu.com/questions/476041/how-do-i-make-rsync-delete-files-that-have-been-deleted-from-the-source-folder and http://askubuntu.com/questions/609968/rsync-delete-option-doesnt-delete-files-in-target-directory and man rsync and ask a new question if needed rather then asking in comments.

Answer (score 15):

I'd suggest using rsync for this purpose.  Rsync is extremely fast, stable, and versatile.  There's a good introduction at http://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync

If you wish, there is an optional graphic front end:  grsync

```
 sudo rsync -azv --exclude 'dir1' /home/path/folderA/ /home/path/folderB
```

The command above will copy from folderA to folderB excluding dir1.  The flags are

```
-a preserves time stamps
-z is to enable compression
-v verbose
```

There are many more options available.

Answer (score 8):

I always found Unison to be very helpful.  It has a text based or GUI based interface, and quite a few different options to tweak it to what you want (with a little fiddling).  It takes quite a bit of time to do the first sync, but after that it's brilliant.  You can make it sync one-way, as you want, but it will pretty much get that automatically.  It can also delete from the backup or not as you choose.

You also may find issues with permissions which are supported in the ubuntu file format, but maybe not in the external hard drive (depending whether the external hard drive is going to be used in a windows machine, this may be a good thing), so you'll want to sync without the permissions potentially.

Anyway, the nice thing is that with the tutorial it's relatively straightforward to set it up once, and thereafter it's a GUI interface whenever you want to do it.

Here's some info about it:
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/unison-file-synchronization-tool.html

And here's the tutorial:
http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#tutorial

Answer (score 4):

```
rsync -avPr --ignore-existing /home/username/Research/ /path/to/other/folder/on/hdd/
```

This will sync and copy only that data that doesn't exist in the `/other/folder/on/hdd/`

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other answers, you can use in **rsync** in Terminal or the interfaces **Grsync**, **luckyBackup**, **Conduit** or the famous **Unison**.

Another great app is **Krusader** (a Twin-Panel File Manager for KDE), in the Tools menu you can find "Syncronize Directories", is very useful.

In last instance you can install *Wine* and install another great twin-pane file manager like *Total Commander*.

Anyway you have plenty of options and all of them are present in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Conduit for simple synchronization. It's available the software system. It does exactly what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

There is a quite handy shell tool called **rsnapshot** - http://www.rsnapshot.org/ -  filesystem snapshot utility for making backups of local and remote systems. that uses rsync and hard links which makes it possible to keep multiple, full file system backups instantly available. Just do `sudo apt-get install rsnapshot` and check `info rsnapshot`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a graphical interface on a system that is highly configurable, give FreeFileSync a try.  See, for example:  http://linuxnorth.wordpress.com/2011/11/29/file-and-folder-synchronization/  In particular, you want the "Update" option for synchronization that will "Copy new or updated files to right folder", i.e. copy from the left folder to the right folder in a two-window display.

Answer (score 0):

You can sync files inside two direcotries by:

```
rsync -rv /path/to/directory1/ /path/to/directory2
```

Doing `rsync -rv /path/to/directory1 /path/to/directory2` will create `directory1` inside `directory2`, like this `/path/to/directory2/directory1/[files]`

You can dry run using `-n` switch, like this `rsync -rnv /path/to/directory1/ /path/to/directory2`

Reference: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories-on-a-vps