# Sync folder with Android via LAN or USB

Tags: android, sync, lan

I am trying to keep my music folder synced between my ubuntu desktop and my android phone.
Both my devices are usually connected via LAN.
I don't wanna use internet to sync.

How can I do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite software for such tasks is [**FreFileSync**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/) (http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/), "*a folder comparison and synchronization tool providing highly optimized performance and usability without a needlessly complex user interface.*"

Ubuntu package and installation instructions can found here: http://launchpad.net/freefilesync

Launch the terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freefilesync/ffs
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install freefilesync
```

OR
You can also have a look at the answers (e.g. **rsync**) here: [How to automatically archive a directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147234/how-to-synchronize-folders)