# Get a list of deleted files from rsync

Tags: command-line, rsync

I synchronise my music collection between:

- My desktop's RAID10, where I rip CDs and download music to, and
- The house media centre, which controls audio players around the house

I do this with a very simple, little rsync command:

```
rsync -av /media/ned/music/ tank:/media/steve/music/
```

Occasionally I'll delete something on my desktop, or rename it. When I sync again Tank keeps the old copy and this can result in duplicates.

I know [there are `--delete-{before/after}` options](https://askubuntu.com/a/476048/449) but I am very apprehensive about automatic deletions. There is no third backup yet, so if I make a mistake (which I have before) and `rsync` nukes my "backup" on Tank, I've lost data.

Is there a way to generate a list of potential deletions after a transfer has finished? Ideally `rsync` would present me the list and give me a `[y/N]` prompt but I'm more than happy doing this in a separate command (I'll just write a `syncmusic` script).

Comment: You can generate a list of potential deletes from the `-n` (dry run) option. Would that work?

Comment: There are a couple of interesting ides here, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1692800, but nothing that does it natively within rsync. Rsync does always precede deleted files with the word 'deleting' which would be an easy grep.

Comment: There is a timestamp of each file - you could also do : rsync -avptr <source> <target>

Comment: I like to use the `diff -r` or I personally like `colordiff -r` (-r for recursive) . I normally run it after `rsync` but you could do it before. If you run this  - files and subfolders that are present in one folder/system but not  in the other will be reported in the output as `<file> not present`

Comment: @the_velour_fog That's a bit heavy for this. There are hundreds of thousands of files it'd have to diff. Even generating and transferring the full lists would take a while.

Comment: I'm writing a music player that syncs to five locations on 3 devices. Copying files between locations, or just updating time stamps when contents the same took some time to code. Now when deleting music files, it will be a bigger challenge to record the song names and apply the operation the next time another device/location is on-line. For Android phone I actually had to create a shadow database of modification times because Android doesn't keep one. This was to prevent resyncing files that didn't really change. Also oldest modification time is the real one when contents are the same.

Comment: I find that the accepted answer doesn't work, but I find that @blueray's does. I'm using GNU rsync version 3.1.2 protocol version 31. Can anyone else report their rsync version, whether it's GNU or BSD, and which answer works for them?

Answer (score 9):

Use the `--dry-run` option.

```
rsync -av --delete --dry-run /media/ned/music/ tank:/media/steve/music/ | grep deleting
```

This prints a list of things `rsync` would delete if you ran the command without the `--dry-run` option.

Comment: Found this works, but only with the trailing slashes on the source and destination paths.  Weird because rsync still lists files considered without the slashes, have noticed that it's always best to include trailing slashes for rsync - probably in the docs. somewhere ;-)

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me, but @blueray's does. Maybe a BSD vs GNU rsync issue? I'm using GNU rsync version 3.1.2  protocol version 31, and `rsync -av --delete --dry-run` does not output any information about which files will be deleted, whereas `rsync -av --delete --dry-run --info=del` does include it, and `rsync -a --delete --dry-run` only prints which files will be deleted, removing the need for the `grep deleting` in this answer.

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me. Here's my command: `rsync -av --delete --dry-run --files-from /home/gabriel/.back_up_linux_pc.files_to_include.txt --exclude-from /home/gabriel/.back_up_linux_pc.files_to_exclude.txt / /media/gabriel/Linux_bak/Backups/rsync/Main_Dell_laptop`. My `rsync --version` is `rsync  version 3.2.7  protocol version 31`.

Answer (score 3):

What you are actually looking for is:

```
rsync --dry-run --delete-after -av --info=DEL  /media/ned/music/ tank:/media/steve/music/
```

If you want to check the progress as well then you can use:

```
rsync --dry-run --delete-after -av --info=DEL,PROGRESS2  /media/ned/music/ tank:/media/steve/music/
```

Comment: The old answer already states to use `--dry-run`.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I am suggesting to use `--info=DEL` instead of `grep`ing the value.

Comment: thanks @blueray, this is exactly what I needed! without `--info=DEL`, my `rsync -av --dry-run` lists all the files to be copied, but doesn't say anything about which ones will be deleted, making it impossible to test `--delete` without `--info=DEL`. ps: i find that lowercase `--info=del` and `progress2` also work.

Comment: I find that with rsync 3.2.3 I need `--info=ALL0,DEL` in order to silence other files, but still show the deleted files.

Comment: I have 100000 files in my output. What keywords should I be searching for to see deleted files? I'm searching for `deleting`, `deleted`, and `remov` and am finding nothing.

Comment: Ok so that was with a dry-run logging to a file with `--log-file`. Once I made it NOT a dry-run, now it shows some lines that say `deleting`. I'd like to see that *before* I remove `--dry-run`, but _none_ of my dry-runs show that. I'm using the latest version of rsync: `3.2.7`