# rsync to download (in one way) files from one server to another

Tags: server, downloads, rsync

I've already tried to follow [How to automatically archive a directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147234/how-to-do-a-one-way-synchronization-between-folders) with no success. Anyway here is my problem: I would like to know if there is some service or program that can run on a server to keep a folder updated with all the file that are created on on another server. I don't need a real sync services, beacuse I don't need to have the same content.

I try to explain better.

1. Server a -> there is a root folder with some files and sub-folders (the files could be very heavy)
2. Server b -> once a day it connects to Server A and download all the file and sub-folders in the root folder of the server A
3. (could be nice but it's not mandatory) Server b -> after finish the download of the files and folders of server A, proceed to delete all the item in the server A to keep it free of space

Both server are running Ubuntu. I've tried the rsync command, but it doesn't seems to work vert well (or maybe I'm doing something wrong, I', not very expert in the linux world): every time I need to stay connected to the server with my user and when it lost the connection it start from the beginning.

Comment: In the other post, it is totally local. You need to add `username@serverB:/path/to/store` to your command. To make it run every day, use a cron job. Here is a how to http://www.selflinux.org/selflinux/html/cron01.html

Comment: @KevInski thanks! I'll try immediately! And what about to delete the file after they been downloading? Is it possibile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have a script with such an example code on Server A:

```
#!/bin/sh
rsync -acz /folder_to_copy username@serverB:/path/to/store
rm -rf /folder_to_remove
```

Keep in mind: Always use `-c` for building a checksum, especially if you copy remotely, even it is slower. If you have spaces in the pathname escape it with a \ (backslash) like this `/path/with/a/space\ here`. But try to avoid **EDIT:** spaces, (not backslashes) ;-D.

Make it executable with `chmod u+x /path/to/script/with/name.sh`

Now, if you run this script, it will first upload all files in `/folder_to_copy` to server B in `/path/to/store`. And then remove (recursively) all files and folders from that directory.

Now you can make a cron job for this script so it will run every night at 3pm e.g.

**Always think about what you do, try to understand the given commands and test everything. man-pages are your friend**

Comment: Ok, thanks for your support! I'm going to create the script and do a lot of testing!

Comment: There was a ` (backtick) after `sh` in line one. I changed it in my post

Comment: You could just use the `--remove-source-files` option with `rsync` to delete files. This way if the some files failed to transfer correctly, they won't be deleted.