# How to trigger anacron start if USB drive connected

Tags: usb, cron, rsnapshot, anacron

There is a script in `/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/anacron` which restarts anacron if leptops are connected to power. Is it possible to have a similar script restart anacron if (a certain) USB-drive is connected, and how? I want to start the backup to my USB-drive using anacron.

Comment: `udev` is the way to go. and .... http://askubuntu.com/questions/25071/how-to-run-a-script-when-a-distinct-flash-drive-is-mounted ;)

Comment: That is most likely the best answer, restarting anacron wont do anything anyway. It will only do something if your cron jobs haven't been running.