# Run a command after a specific USB was plugged in

Tags: usb, execute-command

I want my usb to run a command or a script --like autorun-- when it is plugged in. I've also searching and found out that autorun was not present because of some security reason(s). How do you run a command after a specific type of USB is plugged in ?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu I don't think the answer to that question is very helpful. Instead, see this one: [How to run a script when a specific flash-drive is mounted?](http://askubuntu.com/q/25071/88802) (answer does also apply for just plugging in).

Comment: @gertvdijk There are many duplicates in this sense. That was first that I find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place your script in /usr/local/bin (otherwise this sometimes refuses to work). Then create file **/etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb.rules**. In it, place the line like

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]1", ATTRS{vendor}=="SanDisk ", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/backup.sh"
```

Adapt to your needs. Generally, it works, but , however, i've never tried it on Ubuntu.

Also, don't forget to reload udev to take your new file into account with:

```
udevadm control --reload
```