# Mount external harddrive and one of its subfolders from fstab

Tags: mount, usb-drive, fstab, automount

I'm currently mounting my external harddrive using the following entry in `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=12C23AD8C23AC031    /media/MyBook ntfs-3g auto,users,exec,rw,nobootwait,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

In addition to that, I also need to run `mount` as follows (which I currently only do before starting Steam, but it's getting annoying to constantly do so; I would prefer it was automated):

```
sudo mount --rbind /media/MyBook/Games/SteamData /home/andreas/.local/share/Steam/
```

Is there any way to automatically mount the *SteamData* folder whenever the drive *"My Book"* is mounted? There are answers on how to [run a shell script when a drive is mounted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25071/how-to-run-a-script-when-a-specific-flash-drive-is-mounted), but is it better/possible to do this directly from `fstab`?

Note that my external harddrive may not be available at boot, and may be plugged in at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

the fstab entry would be:

```
/source/dir            /destination/dir    none  bind            0 0
```

or

```
/media/MyBook/Games/SteamData     /home/andreas/.local/share/Steam/   none  bind     0   0
```

be certain you have full perms to this folder, unless you want a r/o mount.

Comment: Would this work even if `MyBook` isn't mounted at boot? (the path `/media/MyBook/Games/SteamData` would not exist) Would it still work if `MyBook` were plugged in later on?

Comment: no.. for hot plugging you would need to use udev rules, and thats over my head as of this moment, but since you have the MyBook in fstab the kernel would throw an error at boot if the device didn't exist at boot time, so it might be wise to just use udev rules to make this work, unless you never remove the device the fstab is the fastest solution

Comment: _"since you have the MyBook in fstab the kernel would throw an error at boot if the device didn't exist at boot time"_ - That's why I used the `nobootwait` flag in the `fstab` entry. Before I learned about it, I used to just press `s` to skip if it wasn't connected at boot.