# Can upstart script be triggered by a device attached?

Tags: 12.04, upstart

How should I specify the "start on" condition to run an upstart script when a device (an external disk) is attached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Have a read of `man upstart-udev-bridge`. Basically anything that can trigger a `udev` script can trigger an Upstart event. There's more in the [Upstart Cookbook's Bridges section](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#bridges).

In your case, we're talking about a block device so here's an example from [a StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3514977/12870) by [deft_code](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28817/deft-code):

```
#thumbdrive_special.conf
start on block-device-added

task

script
   if [ `blkid $DEV` -eq "YOUR-THUMBDRIVES-UUID" ]; then
      /home/you/bin/thumbdrive_special $DEV
   fi
end script
```

The other route is just using [udev to trigger run a script when you plug something in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25071/how-to-run-a-script-when-a-specific-flash-drive-is-mounted). That could be anything, including running a upstart command.

[Upstart has a `mounted` event](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man7/mounted.7.html) but this only comes off the back of the booting mountall call. I don't think it's any use here.

Comment: Is the event trigger if I attach a lopp device (losetup /dev/loop0 backedfile.raw)?

Comment: I honestly don't know what events that would trigger. You could investigate with udevadm.