# WD Elements 1042 External Will not work

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount

I'm trying to get all my data at this point. Any help? Once and a while it will mount but cant get data off quickly.

Error Message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/ubuntu/Elements: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/ubuntu/Elements"' exited with non-zero exit status 21: fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
 (udisks-error-quark, 0)

~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 064e:a103 Suyin Corp. Acer/HP Integrated Webcam [CN0314]
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1058:1042 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x64befb2b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    24578047    12288000   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2   *    24578048    24782847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        24782848   625139711   300178432    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000202043392 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121600 cylinders, total 1953519616 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0002846e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048  1953519615   976758784    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. Here is my workaround:

1. Create folder `/media/wd-elements`
2. Find out **UUID** of your external disk:
   `sudo blkid`
3. Add following line to your `/etc/fstab`:
   `UUID=<UUID> /media/wd-elements ntfs-3g defaults,soft,_netdev,users 0 0`
4. Setup rule to mount your disk when it is plugged. [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25071/how-to-run-a-script-when-a-specific-flash-drive-is-mounted)

If anyone has a better solution, share it please.

**EDIT**: I installed new version of Ubuntu (14.04) and my external disk mounts and unmounts correctly now!

Answer (score 0):

Try rebooting the computer with the drive plugged in. I'd given up on using the drive with Ubuntu and purely by chance I'd left the drive plugged in when I rebooted. 
It's never shown up when I've plugged it in while booted up but showed up immediately after a reboot. It's a 1TB WD USB 3.0 drive.