# Run a script on detecting modem

Tags: usb, mount, scripts, modem

My problem is I am not able to run script automaticlly when modem is connected.

I need a code to be run when my modem is detected. I am having a photon modem and I am using sakis3g script to connect to internet. I have to run **sudo sakis3g connect** in terminal to connect my modem. I have made this code to run without password by editing **sudoers** list. After that I can connect modem by just typing *sudo sakis3g connect* in terminal.

I was reading [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25071/how-to-run-a-script-when-a-specific-flash-drive-is-mounted) post about run a script automatically when usb is mounted and was following steps.

my **lsusb** output is like
 [image]

modem is ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM

I noted down ID "19d2:1254"

ran command  **sudoedit /etc/udev/rules.d/mount-modem.rules**

edited rules to

```
 ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="19d2", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1254", RUN+="/home/bibi/bin/modem.sh"
```

my modem.sh is

[image]

I am able to run modem.sh from terminal and connect modem.

[image]

But when usb modem is removed and connected script is not running. I dont know whether I missed anything.

Thanks

Edit. It is working.... No changes were made. Problem was delay was a little more that made me think not working. Thank you

Comment: if you want to show people the answer, you can provide an answer yourself and mark it as the accepted answer. Editing the title with "[SOLVED]" is not how these stackexchange sites work.

Comment: Any idea @Avinash What should I do here ? http://askubuntu.com/questions/461867/not-able-to-connect-to-the-internet-using-huawei-e303-datacard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working. Whatever steps I followed was correct. No changes were made. Problem was delay was a little more that made me think not working.

Also it was running without any notification.  Normally a window will pop up with 'connecting' dialogue when I run sakis3g to connect internet. No notifications like 'connected' also I  am  getting as showed in question.

But on plugging modem it is  getting connected automatically to internet in few seconds. :)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably that `sakis3g` is not in a default location. Modify your script to use the full path. For example, if `sakis3g` is in your `$HOME/bin` folder, make your script look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 6
/home/bibi/bin/sakis3g connect
```

Comment: I think problem is here because when I changed  ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="19d2", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1254", RUN+="/home/bibi/bin/modem.sh" to  ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="19d2", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1254", RUN+="firefox". Then also modem mount not causing firefox to launch.