# Not able to connect to the internet using HUAWEI E303 datacard

Tags: 14.04, internet, usb-modem

I followed the steps mentioned in the [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323031/how-to-install-ndis-driver-for-huawei-mobile-broadband-devices/368669#comment608341_368669). But now I am not able to connect to the internet using my *HUAWEI E303* datacard. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Could you please guide me on this ?
[image]

Comment: Look at the shaded screen.. there you can see **AIRCEL 2G** is disabled..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of NDIS, you can try with this:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2008275 . Apply to Ubuntu 11.04 but maybe it should work with 14.04

Comment: The package I got with the Datacard itself, from their I did install what was written in the mentioned link. But still my OS not able to connect to internet. I can see *AIRCEL EDGE*, but it is disable in the *Netrwork* section... :(

Comment: Did you try with a reboot and/or extract the dongle and insert it again? Sometimes network manager has this kind of problems...

Comment: Please, execute in a terminal (ctrl-alt-t) the following commands and copy the results:

lspci -nn | grep 0280

rfkill list all

Comment: And please execute the followind command too:
sudo lsusb

Comment: What if you click into New Mobile Broadband Connection option?

Comment: Yes... I did the set up to.. But no connection being established..