# Keyboard / usb detachment alert?

Tags: usb, security, notification, hotplug

I'm in a fun security-battle with a co-worker, where we each try to attach each others system in order to send out an email to all other co-workers in which they are invited to come and have a sweet treat.

I run Ubuntu 14.04 and have an encrypted harddrive. I use a passphrase to unlock that and have a fairly strong password on my account. I automatically lock the screen each time.

I tried to think of attack vectors, and thought of a hardware keylogger. I think that is basically undetectable, but what IS detectable is the detachment of my usb-keyboard.

I tried to built something myself, by reading the output of `lsusb` and calling `notify` if something has changed. This is kinda cumbersome, so basically what I would like to know:

**TL;DR** Is there a tool that provides alerts on usb attachment / detachments of devices?

Answer (score 1):

If he is plugging in a USB, whether is is set up U3 or as a HID device, I believe it will always show up in dmesg.

As far as an unplug alert, you would essentially follow [these udev rule instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25071/how-to-run-a-script-when-a-specific-flash-drive-is-mounted), substituting "add" for "remove"