# Is there a way to run a script every time I insert a usb modem?

Tags: command-line, scripts, usb-modem

I would like a shell script to execute each time I insert a USB modem.

How would I do this?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/25071/how-to-run-a-script-when-a-specific-flash-drive-is-mounted for an example and delve into "udev rules"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with some udev rules, as @Rinzwind suggested.

First, save your script to somewhere accessible by other users. For example, you could save it as `/usr/local/bin/script.sh`.

Now, make the script accessible by others.

```
sudo chmod 555 /usr/local/bin/script.sh
```

Now, plug in your USB modem and then run `lsusb`. Below is an example output:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 0fcf:1008 Dynastream Innovations, Inc. Mini stick Suunto
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Find the line with your modem's name at the end. Now, find the portion near the middle in the format `ID XXXX:####`. The `XXXX` and `####` portions will be, the *Vendor ID* and *Device ID* respectively.

For this example for the third line, which reads `… ID 0fcf:1008 Dynastream …`, the vendor ID is `0fcf` and the Device ID is `1008`. Your device will have different values for these IDs.

Now, we will use these IDs to create a rule for udev.

Now, create a rule for this device with udev.

Make a rules file with

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/90-local.rules
```

Add the following line:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{vendor}=="0xXXXX", ATTRS{device}=="0x####", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/script.sh"
```

Replace `XXXX` with the *vendor id* from earlier, and replace `####` with the *product id* from earlier.

Now, force udev to reload it's rules (alternatively you could skip this step and reboot)

```
udevadm control --reload-rules
sudo service udev restart
```

And you're done!

Sources: [Similar question on SU concerning udev rules](https://superuser.com/q/305723), [Creating udev Rules](https://wiki.debian.org/udev)