# Symbolic links lost after restart

Tags: mount, directory

I have been working on setting up some symbolic links so that I can easily access directories and files on another internal hard drive. When I create the links they work well, but every time that I restart the links are lost. Is there a better way to use links or refresh them?

I am currently creating links like this

```
ln -s /media/UserName/DiskName
```

I am running ubuntu 15.04 64-bit

Comment: Two quick questions: Are the links disappearing or just broken? What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: That command is missing a target.

Comment: @Rinzwind no need for a target if you want the link to be named the same as the source in the current directory.

Comment: Is it an external drive? If so you can use udev-rules to auto-run a script to create the links when the drive is plugged in. See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25071/how-to-run-a-script-when-a-specific-flash-drive-is-mounted) and [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/21327/run-a-command-when-a-disk-is-inserted-linux)

Comment: To clear it up the links are still there, but broken. The drive I am trying to access is a second hard drive on my machine, so ubuntu is on drive A and I have the symbolic link to drive B.

Comment: I like the idea of an auto-script, but I'm not sure it would work as there is never any action for it to detect, unless finding the second hard drive at start up counts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is quite clear. You did not set mounting rules for this disk in `/etc/fstab/`.

When system starts, the disk is not mounted.

Just add a line to `/etc/fstab` for a permanent rule and the problem will be solved.

[This is a guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab).

Comment: That would appear to be the problem, thank you! I found this link to be more helpful however https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions#Systemwide_Mounts

Comment: See [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/858844/111033) for a way that doesn't require you to compose a `/etc/fstab` entry. I will also add that the bug is in nautilus, since after you log in, there's a perfectly valid mounted partition where the symlink expects to find it, yet the link fails.

Comment: There's a nice gui method to sort that problem  here https://askubuntu.com/questions/154180/how-to-mount-a-new-drive-on-startup/588034#588034