# how to automatically copy new files from sd reader to disk on connect?

Tags: bash, scripts, sd-card, copy

im new with ubuntu and linux, and poor knowleadge of english, sorry if i cant write clarely. I need a script or something to automatically move new photos (.cr2) from my camera's sd when i put it on the SD reader. Un windows i have the canon software, but i couldnt make it work on wine. Can it be done with a bash script? I am just learning the basis of linux, so make it myself would take a time

Comment: A script that you manually run after the card is mounted would be pretty simple...

Comment: What is the output of lsblk after mounting?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, my computer broke.

This is the output of lsblk:
`NAME           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT`
`sda              8:0    0 298,1G  0 disk  `
`├─sda1           8:1    0 244,3G  0 part  /`
`├─sda2           8:2    0    50G  0 part  `
`├─sda3           8:3    0     1K  0 part  `
`└─sda5           8:5    0   3,8G  0 part  `
  `└─cryptswap1 252:0    0   3,8G  0 crypt [SWAP]`
`sr0             11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  ` 
`mmcblk0        179:0    0  14,4G  0 disk  `
`└─mmcblk0p1    179:1    0  14,4G  0 part  /media/agustin/EOS_DIGITAL`

Comment: See this : http://askubuntu.com/a/679600/372072

Comment: @Elric Tried it, but its not working... When should i put
´sudo systemctl start your.service´ in the terminal?

Comment: trying some commands i tried  `systemctl` and it throw me this:
`● media-agustin-EOS_DIGITAL.mount                               loaded failed failed    /media/agustin/EOS_DIGITAL`