# Error while running systemd service

Tags: mount, services, systemd

I was following this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/679600/768338). I managed to create the service and the script. But when i start the service it gives error.

```
A dependency job for myusb.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
```

My script is to mount a directory called pop to /mnt automatically.

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/mount /media/raven/BC8B-9F35/pop /mnt
```

I think the issue is with my script.

this is the result of `journalctl -xe`

```
Dec 11 20:47:09 dell systemd[1]: myusb.service: Job myusb.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Dec 11 20:47:09 dell sudo[4547]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root


raven@dell:/etc/systemd/system$ cat myusb.service 
[Unit]
Description=My flashdrive script trigger

Requires=media-raven-BC8B\x2d9F35.mount
After=media-raven-BC8B\x2d9F35.mount

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/raven/script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=media-raven-BC8B\x2d9F35.mount
```

Can anybody help ?

**Day 2**

It worked pretty well but now i'm facing another issue with auto mounting.
I changed my script to mount the entire usb to `/mnt` instead of a specific directory as asked yesterday.

And it is mounting the USB to `/mnt` without issue.

But the issue is that the system itself mounts the USB to default `/media` after that. So when i'm listing the contents in `/mnt` i got nothing but `/media` is full of my usb contents.

and when i run mount command i get the following output.

```
/dev/sdb1 on /mnt type vfat (rw,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdc1 on /media/raven/BC8B-9F351 type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)
```

You can see that it mounts my USB as sdc1 in `/media` and sdb1 in `/mnt`.

Actually i have only one USB or external drive attached to this machine.
So it should mount the sdb1.

So i disabled the auto mounting by the following command.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount false
```

But still the same.

Any help ?

Comment: There is a issue with how systemd handles escapes in `WantedBy` versis `Requires` or `After`. Change the `WantedBy` to add a second escape, `WantedBy=media-raven-BC8B\\x2d9F35.mount`.

Comment: @J.Starnes thanks for the help. anyway it worked today without the `\\` i don't know why.