# Server: Automount USB drive with systemd

Tags: server, mount, encryption

I have a server running Ubuntu Server 20.04 and I want to launch a script as soon as a known USB Encrypted (LUKS) device is plugged in into the server.

For launching the script, I already have the script and a `systemd` service that starts the service after the drive is mounted:

**/etc/systemd/system/mybackup.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Backup
Requires=mnt-encrypted.mount
After=mnt-encrypted.mount

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/script.sh
```

For the external USB Encrypted drive, I have an entry into **/etc/crypttab**

```
encrypted UUID=<UUID> /path/to/key luks,noauto
```

And a service into **/etc/systemd/system/mnt-encrypted.mount**

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount unit for backup

[Mount]
What=/dev/mapper/encrypted
Where=/mnt/encrypted
Options=defaults
```

However, I know that the **mnt-encrypted.mount** Unit is incomplete. It has to run after the generated file by **systemd-cryptsetup-generator**, so the volume has been decrypted and can be mounted.

How can I do that? or, what is missing in my **mnt-encrypted.mount** file?

**Edit**

After reading different posts here and there (added at the end) I finally understood that `systemd` does not mount your drive automatically when you plugin the drive. It is `udev` the one that will trigger the mounting, and you can indicate to do it through `systemd`.

Things that have to be done:

- Add an entry to `/etc/crypttab` if the disk is encrypted
- Modify `/etc/fstab` with an entry for the external drive. This will generate a `systemd` unit for the mount
- Copy the `systemd`` service that will start the backup when the disk is mounted
- Create an `udev` rules that will start the `systemd` service when the disk is plugged in

For example:

```
[Unit]
Description=Backup service
Requires=mnt-human-readable-label.mount
After=mnt-human-readable-label.mount

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/backup-script.sh
User=your-user
Group=your-group

[Install]
WantedBy=mnt-human-readable-label.mount
```

`/etc/crypttab`

```
human-readable-label UUID=your-disk-uuid /path/to/key luks,noauto,nofail
```

`/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/mapper/human-readable-label /mnt/human-readable-label ext4     defaults,noauto,nofail,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=15s,x-systemd.idle-timeout=30 0 0
```

`/etc/udev/rules.d/99-my-usb-dribe.rules` (Use `lsusb` for getting the Product id)

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idProduct}=="id-product", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="external-backup.service", TAG+="systemd"
```

Then:

```bsh
# Copy the systemd service that will start the backup script to the right place
sudo cp external-drive/external-backup.service /etc/systemd/system/external-backup.service

# Reload file system services for creating mount services for the external drive
sudo systemctl restart local-fs.target
sudo systemctl restart remote-fs.target

# Enable the backup service
sudo systemctl enable external-backup.service

# Reload the UDEV ruls
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules

# Reload systemd daemon
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Different sources I used:

- http://jasonwryan.com/blog/2014/01/20/udev/
- https://withblue.ink/2020/01/19/auto-mounting-encrypted-drives-with-a-remote-key-on-linux.html
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246935/set-systemd-service-to-execute-after-fstab-mount
- [How to run a script when a specific flash-drive is mounted?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25071/how-to-run-a-script-when-a-specific-flash-drive-is-mounted)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/766506/automount-usb-drives-with-systemd
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/570987

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks. Helped me alot to achieve more or less the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old enough question and problem probably already resolved, but mounts, as all other systemd units, should support dependencies

> [The common configuration items are configured in the generic [Unit] and [Install] sections.](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html)

So adding following [Install] section should be enough:

```
[Install]
After = systemd-cryptsetup-generator.service
```

(i'm not sure if systemd-cryptsetup-generator is a service, but if it's anything else, changing extension should be enough)

Comment: Thanks for you answer Etki. I already solved my issue and learnt a lot during the process. I'll update my answer with the key things that I was missing.